# How do we debug/see the request being set over API with Moya?

Tags: ios, swift, moya

How do we debug the request being set over to backend servers?

I'd like to be able to see exactly or print out the full request with headers parameters, etc... that is being sent over to servers whenever I make any request by `Moya`

Comment: use `NetworkLoggerPlugin.swift --> willSend ` in moya you get the complete request

Comment: for e.g you get the sample from [here](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/1637)

Comment: Thanks for your response. with your permission I add it as an answer, so it could help others.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is done by activating a plugin that `Moya` Already has it. it is `NetworkLoggerPlugin`. I need to change this line of code:

```
var provider = MoyaProvider<MainAPI>()
```

with:

```
var provider = MoyaProvider<MainAPI>(plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)])
```

MOYA >= 14

```
let plugin: PluginType = NetworkLoggerPlugin(configuration: .init(logOptions: .verbose))

let provider = MoyaProvider<T>(plugins: [plugin])
```

Thanks to @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: happy to see this

Comment: from moya 14.0 onwards we can't use `verbose: true`

Comment: from Moya 14 we can't use it

Answer (score 12):

Starting from Moya 14.0 you need to do this:

```
let loggerConfig = NetworkLoggerPlugin.Configuration(logOptions: .verbose)
let networkLogger = NetworkLoggerPlugin(configuration: loggerConfig)    
let provider = MoyaProvider<YourAPI>(plugins: [networkLogger])
```

Answer (score 7):

If using Moya from 14, you can make your own verbose Plugin, like this:

```
struct VerbosePlugin: PluginType {
    let verbose: Bool

    func prepare(_ request: URLRequest, target: TargetType) -> URLRequest {
        #if DEBUG
        if let body = request.httpBody,
           let str = String(data: body, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("request to send: \(str))")
        }
        #endif
        return request
    }
}
```

and use: `let provider = MoyaProvider<AuthService>(plugins: [VerbosePlugin(verbose: true)])`

Answer (score 6):

For Moya 14.0 and onwards use like this

```
let plugin: PluginType = NetworkLoggerPlugin(configuration: .init(logOptions: .verbose))

let provider = MoyaProvider<T>(plugins: [plugin])
```

Answer (score 3):

[Cross-posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62391144/5798577):

Here's a working example of a verbose plugin that will display both request and response data.

Add the following code to wherever you are calling Moya from:

```
struct VerbosePlugin: PluginType {
    let verbose: Bool

    func prepare(_ request: URLRequest, target: TargetType) -> URLRequest {
        #if DEBUG
        if let body = request.httpBody,
           let str = String(data: body, encoding: .utf8) {
            if verbose {
                print("request to send: \(str))")
            }
        }
        #endif
        return request
    }

    func didReceive(_ result: Result<Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType) {
        #if DEBUG
        switch result {
        case .success(let body):
            if verbose {
                print("Response:")
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: body.data, options: .mutableContainers) {
                    print(json)
                } else {
                    let response = String(data: body.data, encoding: .utf8)!
                    print(response)
                }
            }
        case .failure( _):
            break
        }
        #endif
    }

}
```

In your set up, add the new plugin:

```
let APIManager = MoyaProvider<API>( plugins: [
    VerbosePlugin(verbose: true)
    ])
```

This will output both the request being made and the response returned. If the response is JSON encoded, it will pretty-print the JSON, otherwise it will attempt to print out the raw response data.

Answer (score 0):

1. use this to setup the provider `let provider: MoyaProvider<API> = MoyaProvider<API>(plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin()]`
2. in `NetworkLoggerPlugin.swift` file of Moya pod you can change `logOptions` inside the `Configuration` struct given. In the init method `logOptions: LogOptions = .requestBody` can be changed. It's an enum. So you can try changing the logOptions value as you wish.

*** I think it's okay to change a pod file because it doesn't affect the code base since this is a developer side logging option**

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to see my log request and response in the compiler using NetworkLoggerPlugin logOptions? Thank you. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479627/logging-response-and-request-in-moya-14)