# Logging response and request in Moya 14

Tags: swift, moya

Is there any way to log my request and response in Moya 14 without using verbose?

```
container.register(NetworkLoggerPlugin.self) { r in
   NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)
   }.inObjectScope(.container)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The initial guidance has been given [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61063371/5798577) to create a custom plugin for Moya, but here's a working example of a verbose plugin that will display both request and response data.

Add the following code to wherever you are calling Moya from:

```
struct VerbosePlugin: PluginType {
    let verbose: Bool

    func prepare(_ request: URLRequest, target: TargetType) -> URLRequest {
        #if DEBUG
        if let body = request.httpBody,
           let str = String(data: body, encoding: .utf8) {
            if verbose {
                print("request to send: \(str))")
            }
        }
        #endif
        return request
    }

    func didReceive(_ result: Result<Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType) {
        #if DEBUG
        switch result {
        case .success(let body):
            if verbose {
                print("Response:")
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: body.data, options: .mutableContainers) {
                    print(json)
                } else {
                    let response = String(data: body.data, encoding: .utf8)!
                    print(response)
                }
            }
        case .failure( _):
            break
        }
        #endif
    }

}
```

In your set up, add the new plugin:

```
let APIManager = MoyaProvider<API>( plugins: [
    VerbosePlugin(verbose: true)
    ])
```

This will output both the request being made and the response returned. If the response is JSON encoded, it will pretty-print the JSON, otherwise it will attempt to print out the raw response data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specific log options:

```
MoyaProvider(plugins: [
    NetworkLoggerPlugin(configuration: .init(
       logOptions: [.requestBody, .successResponseBody, .errorResponseBody]
    ))
])
```

Answer (score -2):

MoyaProvider(plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin()])

Comment: this is a built-in class to use to print activities.