# Moya won't show response body only

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I'm using Moya version 14.0.0 in my project. i'm using NetworkLoggerPlugin, to see request and response, my problem is moya logger won't show response body (showing header and response header only).

this is my code to using NetworkLoggerPlugin:

```
someProvider<TransferWebServicesAPI>(plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin()])
```

moya logger working perfectly before but after a while (and i don't know why) it did't show response body any more?

Comment: try with `NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)`

Comment: that's worked for me but, in moya 14 and onwards we have to use like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914638/8425034